# Writing Strings in multiple lines using Qstring

Tags: qt5, newline, qstring

I'm trying to create a string which must output info in several lines. Earlier I was using Qt4 and `QString( "\n" )` was perfectly working, but as I migrated to qt5, the output won't be written in multiple lines but instead the "\n" will be added to the beginning of each output expression. This is how the output looks like:

> tempString = "\nC 1 Guidance       \nC 2 LINE            AREA                        MAP ID             \nC 3  YEAR      OBSERV  \nC 5 RECORD        AUXILIARY RECORD         CDF FOLD          \nC 6 SAMPLE INTERVAL         SAMPLES/TRACE       BITS/IN     BYTES/SAMPLE        \nC 7 RECORDING FORMAT        FORMAT THIS REEL        MEASUREMENT SYSTEM          \nC 8 SAMPLE: FLOATING PT     FIXED PT     FIXED PT-GAIN     CORRELATED      \nC 9  FIXED

The output using qt4 was:

> tempString = "
> \nC 1 Guidance
> \nC 2 LINE            AREA                        MAP ID             \nC 3  YEAR      OBSERV
> \nC 5 RECORD        AUXILIARY RECORD         CDF FOLD
> \nC 6 SAMPLE INTERVAL         SAMPLES/TRACE       BITS/IN
> \nC 7 RECORDING FORMAT        FORMAT THIS REEL        MEASUREMENT
> \nC 8 SAMPLE: FLOATING PT     FIXED PT     FIXED PT-GAIN
> \nC 9  FIXED

Here is the part of my code which creates the string:

```
QString tempString = QString( "\n" );
                QDataStream readFile( &recordFile );
                readFile.setByteOrder( config->getISDataByteOrder() );
                readFile.setVersion( QDataStream::Qt_5_5 );
                for ( int i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {
                    for ( int j = 0; j < 80; j++ ) {
                        readFile >> temp->textualHeader[ i ][ j ];
                    }
                }
                
                temp->convertTextualHeader( true );
                for ( int i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {
                    for ( int j = 0; j < 80; j++ ) {
                        //qDebug() << "temp->textualHeader[" << i << "][" << j << "] =" << temp->textualHeader[ i ][ j ] << ";";
                        tempString += QString( temp->textualHeader[ i ][ j ] );
                    }
                    tempString += QString( "\n" );
                }
                qDebug() << "tempString =" << tempString << ";";
```

Does anybody has an idea why QString( "\n" ) doesn't create new lines in this case?

Comment: According to the [`QDebug` documentation for `Qt5`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-16) that's the expected behaviour.  Possibly changed from `Qt4` to `Qt5`.

Comment: But I'm defining the string first (in multiple lines) and then giving it to qDebug, logically it must stay in the same form as created by Qstring, doesn't it?

Comment: If that's the case then you need to provide more information.  What is `temp` and what does `textualHeader` do?  What are the contents of the `QDataStream` `readFile` etc.?  Please try to provide a [mcve].